# NSURLSession error: bad URL, works in the browser

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, nsurlsession

I am fetching posts from facebook with the below session and get back 'bad url' error. When I take the same URL and open it in a browser, I get back proper JSON full of posts. What is the problem with my session? Thanks.

```
- (void)loadFacebookPosts
{
    NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];
    [[session dataTaskWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://graph.facebook.com/profileid/feed?fields=message,description,caption,name&access_token=appid|secret"]
            completionHandler:^(NSData *data,
                                NSURLResponse *response,
                                NSError *error) {

                NSLog(@"error: %@", error);
                NSLog(@"data: %@", data);
                NSLog(@"response: %@", response);

            }] resume];
}
```

Console:

```
2014-02-11 21:36:10.507 fbFetch [34365:310b] error: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1000 "bad URL" UserInfo=0xc7844f0 {NSUnderlyingError=0xc634c90 "bad URL", NSLocalizedDescription=bad URL}
2014-02-11 21:36:10.509 fbFetch [34365:310b] data: <>
2014-02-11 21:36:10.510 fbFetch [34365:310b] response: (null)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you try:

```
NSString *strURL = [@"https://graph.facebook.com/profileid/feed?fields=message,description,caption,name&access_token=appid|secret" stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Then use the strURL to create the `NSURL`.

Comment: Bingo!! Don't understand the difference yet, but this is it. Thanks a million :)

Comment: the method `-stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding` escapes the incompatible characters to that a regular url is formed. Incompatible characters are percent escaped.

Comment: I knew this, but did not realize any incompatible characters are present. Now I see, the issue is the character '|' between token and secret. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

Your URL contains illegal character - '|' so you need to use percent-encode string before create URL from it:

```
NSString *URLString = @"https://graph.facebook.com/profileid/feed?fields=message,description,caption,name&access_token=appid|secret";  
NSString *escapedURLString = [URLString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];
    [[session dataTaskWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString: escapedURLString]
            completionHandler:^(NSData *data,
                                NSURLResponse *response,
                                NSError *error) {

                NSLog(@"error: %@", error);
                NSLog(@"data: %@", data);
                NSLog(@"response: %@", response);

            }] resume];
```